# Time Zone used for the "days visited" profile notation

Tags: discussion

Although I visit this site every day, sometimes it is in the morning, sometimes the afternoon and sometimes at night.  I regularly get my "days visited" information getting reset because I have obviously not visited within an appropriate 24 hour time period governed by this site.  Could someone provide me to the link, I missed or I am blind.
Regards

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile

Comment: Thanks very much Mapperz ... we will go with the blind conclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filling an answer here,

I am on -3 time zone, and my SE day begins at 9:00 PM (21:00 h).

So I think the correct answer is the zero time zone or [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](http://geography.about.com/od/timeandtimezones/a/gmtutc.htm).
UTC replaced the former system [Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time), in 1972.

[image]

Source: Pidwirny, M. (2006). "Map Location and Time Zones". Fundamentals of Physical Geography, 2nd Edition.
Accessed from: http://www.physicalgeography.net/fundamentals/2c.html

Comment: A small pedantic correction. The Time Zone is called [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). There are a few minor differences between UTC and GMT

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe, thank's a lot. It is not pedantic, but the correct information. I edited the answer. Please, feel free to edit it again, if necessary.